# OpenXML feedData() not feeding in all data

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml

I have a template powerpoint slide which contains all the relevant data I'd like to feed into another powerpoint slide I have created. I use the feedData() method to copy over that information which works for the most part (images, text, etc all good) however it always fails to copy over chartpart information.

My new slide is created like this:

```
string slidename = new string(name.Where(char.IsLetterOrDigit).ToArray()) + DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
SlidePart newSlide = part.AddNewPart<SlidePart>(slidename);
```

And it is fed in data from templateSlide:

```
newSlide.FeedData(templateSlide.GetStream());
```

Looking at the templateSlide it definitely has chart part data:

[image]

However when I check my newSlide after the feed data, it is missing the chart part:

[image]

What can I do to get the chart part data to copy over into my newSlide?

EDIT: Here's what it looks like in OpenXML:

[image]

Comment: Probably the chart is an embedded xlsx file, you should be able to locate it with the open xml productivity tool

Comment: I've added what the OpenXML Productivity tool says; I don't think it's embedded

Comment: "A chart is placed within a slide by a <p:graphicFrame> element, which in turn contains the typical <a:graphicData> element noted above, which contains a <c:chart> element. That element references a **separate part** chart1.xml (or chart2.xml, etc) which defines the chart." [Source](http://officeopenxml.com/drwOverview.php)

Comment: You are absolutely correct; that chart required an extra stream to get into the pptx. I'll update this question with the answer when I next get the chance - many thanks for pointing in the right direction :)